# Getting root (Nan) while implementing D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am getting Nan while implementing D3.js. I was following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022) 
tutorial.
I think I have problem while looping the json file to extract the data.
Here is the code which I am using in html file to get data from json file.

```html
if (window.location.hash === "") {
  //console.log("inside the if condition")
    d3.json("d3_sample.json", function(err, res) {
        //console.log(res);
        //function(d){return d3.all;},
        // if (err) {
        //   //console.log("error occured")
        //   console.log(err);  
        // } else {
          //console.log("no error occured")
        if (!err) {  
          console.log(res);
          var data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.region; })
            .key(function(d) { return d.subregion; })
            .entries(res);
          
          //console.log(data);
          //console.log(data);
          main({title: "Snapdeal Product categories follows by price"}, {key: "root", values: data});
        }
    });
```

And this is the link for the [index.html](https://github.com/ashvinikumar/snap_vis/blob/master/index.html) file.

And here is the json file [d3_sample.json](https://github.com/ashvinikumar/snap_vis/blob/master/d3_sample.json)

I am sure I am missing something in html while making tree with d3.nest()
Here is the full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ashvinikumar/snap_vis)

Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `region` or a `subregion` key in that JSON?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, I don't have region and subregion in JSON, please help me to figure out, I am new in D3 and js.

Comment: I know you don't, it was just a rhetorical question. You can't take his/her code and simply changing the JSON like that, you have to modify the code accordingly. Unfortunately, it seems to me that you need a tutorial, which is out of the scope of SO.

Comment: Any guidance which can let me do the job, would be much appreciated.